# Is there an existing implementation to save an Octomap octree as a PCD file?

Tags: ros, pcd, octomap-mapping, octree

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am wondering if there is already a way to save an octree generated with Octomap as a pcd file?

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9367/is-there-an-existing-implementation-to-save-an-octomap-octree-as-a-pcd-file?/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made it myself, inspired by the code from octomap_server:

```
#include <octomap/octomap.h>
#include <octomap/OcTreeLabeled.h>

#include "pcl/io/pcd_io.h"
#include "pcl/point_types.h"

...

void buildCloud(OcTree tree)
{
    //how many occupied cells do we have in the tree?
    std::list<octomap::OcTreeVolume> occupiedCells;
    tree.getOccupied(occupiedCells);
    
    //cloud to store the points
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
    cloud.points.resize(occupiedCells.size());
    
    std::list<octomap::OcTreeVolume>::iterator it;
    int i=0;
    for (it = occupiedCells.begin(); it != occupiedCells.end(); ++it, i++)
    {
        //add point in point cloud
        cloud.points[i].x = it->first.x();
        cloud.points[i].y = it->first.y();
        cloud.points[i].z = it->first.z();      
    }   
    //save cloud
    pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII ("file.pcd", cloud);
}
```

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-10**:
You might want to structure this more in a public package.